# Disable automatic convenience initializer inheritance in Swift

Tags: swift, oop, inheritance

I have a class (let's say `Foo`) which has two initializers, one of which is designated and the other is a `convenience init`. They look something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    init(object: SomeObject) {
        self.object = object
        // Do something with object…
    }

    public convenience init() {
        self.init(object: SomeObject())
    }
}
```

`Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, and being more specialised it configures the `SomeObject()` instance before calling `Foo`'s designated initialiser

```
public class Bar {
    public convenience init(arg: Arg) {
        let object = SomeObject(arg: arg)
        // Configure object…
        self.init(object: object)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, since `Bar` meets all the conditions required for [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222), it also inherits `Foo`'s `convenience` initialiser which does not expect any arguments. This does not make sense for `Bar`, since the special behaviour I mentioned before occurs in its `convenience init` method.

Is there a way to disable Automatic Initializer Inheritance? If not, would it be possible to change the inherited `convenience init` to be `private`? If neither of these are possible, I'm also open to rethinking the class structure and doing it another way. In that case I can also provide more detail (such as what `Foo` and `Bar` are) if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it - the solution was to simply remove the `convenience` keyword from `Bar`'s initializer. Since this breaks the first rule of Automatic Inheritance, `Bar` doesn't inherit `Foo`'s convenience init anymore but can still call `Foo`'s designated init via `super.init(object: object)`.

Comment: To elaborate, a subclass will by default inherit all of its superclass' init methods (including convenience ones) if it does not provide a (non convenience) initializer of its own.